# Unable to get correct output while controlling arduino using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, arduino-ide

I am building a code which turns on RED Led at "12" pin of arduino when red trackbar in opencv(using python) is set at 255 position and turns off the same led when green trackbar is set at 255 position.But arduino gives me a flashing led at pin "13" for the following code:

**Python code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import serial
from time import sleep
def judge(b,g,r,s):
    if r==255 and g==0 and b==0 and s==0:
        print "Fire_alarm_on"
        ser=serial.Serial(3)
        sleep(0.1)
        ser.write('H')
        ser.close()
    elif r==0 and g==255 and b==0 and s==0:
        print "Fire_alarm_off"
        ser=serial.Serial(3)
        sleep(0.1)
        ser.write('B')
        ser.close()
    else:
        pass
def nothing(colour):
    pass
img=np.zeros([300,512,3],np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.createTrackbar('R','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('G','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('B','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s','image',0,1,nothing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    b=cv2.getTrackbarPos('B','image')
    g=cv2.getTrackbarPos('G','image')
    r=cv2.getTrackbarPos('R','image')
    s=cv2.getTrackbarPos('s','image')
    if s==0:
        img[:]=[b,g,r]
    elif s==1:
        img[:]=0
    judge(b,g,r,s)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**arduino code:**

```
int a;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    a=((int)Serial.read())-48;
    Serial.println(a);
    if(a==24)
    {
      Serial.println(a);
      digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    }
    else if(a==18)
    {
      Serial.println(a);
      digitalWrite(12,LOW);
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: perhaps it starts counting at 0? Try `pinMode(11, OUTPUT)` etc

Comment: @Ashalynd Thanks for the help But in arduino declaration deals directly with pin itself Anway i tried your solution.But it didn't work for me